# Is it possible to create a blow functionality without detecting voice?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I need to create a blow functionality. I am using AVAudioRecorder for this. The problem is that my app along with the detection of blow also detects voice. What I want is to just detect the blow.
Please guide me.
I am using code from the given link
https://github.com/dcgrigsby/MicBlow